# Unable to add iOS app properly into my firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase

I am not able to add ios app into my firebase project.

```
)]}'
{"code":7,"errorSpace":"generic","placeholders": {"trackingId":"7308964038394282131"},"status":403,"message":"backend error"}
```

I am getting above error on adding the app into the project.
And when downloading the plist config file it gets downloaded with "1" file without any extension where chrome says Failed - Forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Use `Safari` i have also face this problem.

Comment: Ironically Safari was my issue, just used Firefox to solve a problem adding an app to firebase.